# (Javascript- HTML Parser) Can be html parsed with javascript without server languages?

Tags: javascript, jquery, parsing, html-parsing

Can html be parsed with javascript without server languages?

my webpage should do :

parsing of all images from the url that user enter.

Can I do it only with Javascript if yes with library functions that exist doing that?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can be html parsed with javascript without server languages?

Yes . HTML can be parsed by javascript .

However , you can not make a request to another domain from the client side . The Same origin policy would prevent you from doing that . 
If you want to parse a HTML page that comes from some other domain then you need to do that on the server side .

Comment: Ok, Which library can do it? can you supply link please